# How can I catch a user's Discord ID in the redirect url of Spotify's Oauth2 Flow

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, discord.js, spotify

Trying to build a discord bot to allow users to control their spotify account. I am building a REST API using expressjs in node to handle this. I have a firebase database and I want table columns to be identified using end user's discord ID.

When a user logs into spotify using the bot, I want the bot to store their auth tokens in the database under their discord ID.

However I can't pass their discord ID to the Oauth2 redirect so I cannot add the access token to the correct  document in the database.

Here is the relevant code

```js
    //returns an auth url for end user to authorize application to access their Spotify account
    app.get('/spotifyLoginUrl', (req, res) => {
        const sc = new SpotifyController();
        const authURL = sc.getLoginUrl();
        res.status(200).send(authURL);
    });

    //redirect if user allows access to their Spotify account, gets access token
    app.get('/spotifyAuth', async (req, res) => {
        const code = req.query.code;
        const sc = new SpotifyController();
        const token = sc.spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code);
        token.then((data) => {
             res.status(200).send(data);
         });;
    });
```

The res.send() in the redirect gets lost so I have nowhere to return the token to and I also cannot access the user's discord info from the promise callback..

Comment: I think you can use ["state"](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/#:~:text=slashes%2C%20and%20such.-,state,-Optional%2C%20but%20strongly) for this purpose. Note: I have seen a couple of posts of people who made a Discord bot, and got rejected for a quota extension.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm going to use state. I just wonder how reliable / secure it is. It feels a bit hacky but if it works Im going to keep it

Comment: You can add some text (the actual state) to the end and then base64 encode it. After the authorisation, base64 decode it, and remove the extra text to get the Discord ID back.

Comment: cant capture state in redirect. its encrypted :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this theory of mine doesn't work... I've should've tested it myself first.